# unrecognized selector sent to class CCAnimation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to get an Animation Helper with a cocos2d project and for some reason keep getting an error message:

```
unrecognized selector sent to class.
```

I have tried numerous approaches to no avail.  I understand that it may have to do with a class-instance conflict, but I  do not  know how to resolve it.  Any thoughts?

This is how I am calling the helper function:

```
CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrame:playerAnimName frameCount:1 delay:0.08f];
```

And this is the helper function itself:

```
     +(CCAnimation*) animationWithFrame:(NSString*)frame frameCount:(int)frameCount       delay:(float)delay
{
printf("start helper");

// load the players's animation frames as textures and create a sprite frame
NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frameCount];
for (int i = 1; i < frameCount+1; i++)
{
    NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", frame, i];
    CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    [frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"maze-art.plist"];


    CCSpriteFrame* frame = [frameCache spriteFrameByName:file];
    [frames addObject:frame];
}

// return an animation object from all the sprite animation frames
return [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:delay];
}
```

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is that method in a category? And is that category compiled, linked and loaded?

Answer (score 0):

In order for category to work, you must define the new method in the following way. Please refer to this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

```
@interface ClassName ( CategoryName )
// method declarations
@end
```

For example, your new method must be defined as

```
@interface CCAnimation (Helper)
+(CCAnimation*) animationWithFile:(NSString*)name frameCount:(int)frameCount delay:(float)delay
{
       ...
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do your helper method is? If it is inside your own class, that you have to call it as

```
[MyClass method];
```

not

```
[CCAnimation method];
```

`+` means that method is static so you must call it with the class inside which this method is.